# How to mock the JavaScript function while writing unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to write a unit test for a JavaScript async function , I am using jest. I posting the function below

myClient.js

```
const {authClient} = require("../service/gMemry");

const getResource = async(req,res) =>{
 try{
     const gMemory = authClient(req.header['px-token'];
     const result = await gMemory.api(conFigItem.auth.clientId).get();
     if(!result){
        return res.sendStatus(401).send();
     }
      res.send({result});
    }catch(e){
     res.sendStatus(401).send({result:null]);
   }
  };
```

myClientManager.js

```
 const graph = require('@microsoft/mirosoft-graph-client);
 require('isomorphic-fetch');

 authClient = (accessToken)=>{
 const client = graph.Client.init({
 authProvider : (done) => {
 done(null,accessToken);
  }
});
```

myClient.spec.js

```
 import {getResource} from "./docs";

 describe('getResource' , () =>{
   it('auth req & response' , async()=>{
    const mockReq = {
     headers :{
       'px-token':'my-token',
     },
    };
   ...............
```

i am getting the below exception

authClient is not defined

> authClient = (accessToken)=>{

How i can write the unit test for this method, please help ,i am new to javascript unit test.

Comment: `const authClient`

Comment: Format your code, and make it executable. There are a lot of syntax errors